# Note 10+ not showing up in Device Manager while in fastboot

Tags: samsung, rooting, fastboot, bootloader, usb-drivers

I'm trying to unlock my bootloader so that I can root my Samsung Galaxy Note 10 plus.

The problem is that `fastboot devices` doesn't show any devices, so I found out that I need to install new fastboot drivers.

The first step is to locate your phone in Device Manager while it is in fastboot, but my phone is not showing up in in Device Manager at all while in fastboot.

Usually when I plug in my phone (or any device) into my PC the Device Manager refreshes and I hear the sound Windows makes when a new device is detected, but none of those thing happen if I connect my phone that is in fastboot.

I know that the USB port and cable are working because `adb devices` and Device Manager work fine and actually show my phone when it's not in fastboot.

So how do I install new fastboot drivers without the Device Manager?

OR

How do I make the Device Manager detect my phone while it's in fastboot?

Comment: Even if you don't have any driver installed at least one entry should be visible in device manager. I would try it this way: boot to regular OS so that adb gets visible. Select this entry in device manager and switch view to device by connection so you should see the USB host entry you phone is connected to. Then reboot to fastboot made and check what device is now showed as node connected to the identified USB controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that Samsung phones have a different way to unlock the bootloader.

You need to power off your device, then hold both the volume up and down buttons and plug in your phone while doing that (I'm not sure if you have to plug it into a PC or if a charger is good enough). That will boot your phone to the Download mode splash screen where you can choose to unlock the bootloader if you have "OEM unlocking" enabled in developer options.